# WeatherMap not giving the expected output in python

Tags: python

I was trying to do a weather script in python which the user can input a city and it tells what temperature is there. But this code doesn't work. I'm using OpenWeatherAPI. Here is the code:

```
import requests

def get_temperature(city_name):
    base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
    params = {
        "q": city_name,
        "units": "metric" 
    }

    response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
    data = response.json()

    if response.status_code == 200:
        temperature = data["main"]["temp"]
        return temperature
    else:
        print("Error fetching temperature data.")
        return None

def main():
    city_name = input("Enter the name of the city: ")

    temperature = get_temperature(city_name)
    if temperature is not None:
        print(f"The current temperature in {city_name} is {temperature}°C.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I did some searches online but still didn't find the fix to this problem!

Comment: I think that you've missed the api_key

Answer (score 0):

Always check for errors, particularly when interacting with external things, such as that API. I'd add the following type of try / except to ANY web request you make:

```
...
response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
try:
    response.raise_for_status()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Request failed with error: {e}")
    raise
data = response.json()
...
```

This clearly shows the problem:

`requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url`

You're missing the API key. Check the sign up docs here :: https://openweathermap.org/appid